# Python: Animation for scatter plot with varying colours wont work

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, scatter, cartopy

I am trying to animate a scatter plot on a cartopy map in jupyter notebook using FuncAnimation from matplotlib. When i run the code there are no error messages, but the animation does not show up. This is my code:

```
%matplotlib notebook
from matplotlib import animation

# Sets up the map plot with coastlines from cartopy and the PlateCarree projection
# The PlateCarree projection is neither equal area nor conformal, thus it is mostly used for thematic mapping
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(9,5))
cmap=matplotlib.cm.RdBu_r 
norm=matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=50)
ax=plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(),extent=[-180, 180, -90, 90])
# Set labels and ticks for x- and y-axis
ax.set_xticks([-180, -120, -60, 0, 60, 120, 180], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_yticks([-90, -60, -30, 0, 30, 60, 90], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
plt.xlabel('Longitude [deg]')
plt.ylabel('Latitude [deg]')

plot = plt.scatter([], [], c=[], s=40, norm=norm, cmap=cmap, edgecolor="k")

def init():
    plot.set_offsets([])
    plot.set_array([])
    return plot,

def animate(i):
    data = np.hstack((nphi[i], nthe[i]))
    plot.set_offsets(data)
    plot.set_array(mag[i])
    return plot,

# Sets up colourbar and set a label
cbar=plt.colorbar()
cbar.set_label('Magnitude of SV [nT/yr$^2$]')

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, interval=800, blit=True)
```

The variables "nphi", "nthe", and "mag" are all arrays with several subarrays, so all i want is to have an animation that plots a scatter plot with a new set of data from those arrays for coordinates and colours in each loop. What am i doing wrong?

Minimal reproducible example:

```
# Setting up script by importing libraries and functions as well as using 
magic
# Magic line of code that Jupyter Notebook needs to display interactive 
figures nicely when using matplotlib
%matplotlib notebook
# Time is used to display execution time of functions
import time
# Numpy is used for most array and math operations
import numpy as np
# The function loadmat is imported from scipy to load .mat data files
from scipy.io import loadmat
# Cartopy is used for projections of world map 
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
# Matplotlib.pyplot is used for most plots 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Matplotlib.cm and Matplotlib.colors is used for colourbars
import matplotlib.cm
import matplotlib.colors
from matplotlib import animation

nphi = [np.random.randint(1,180,30),np.random.randint(1,180,30),np.random.randint(1,180,30),np.random.randint(1,180,30),np.random.randint(1,180,30)]
nthe = [np.random.randint(1,90,30),np.random.randint(1,90,30),np.random.randint(1,90,30),np.random.randint(1,90,30),np.random.randint(1,90,30)]
mag = [np.random.randint(1,50,30),np.random.randint(1,50,30),np.random.randint(1,50,30),np.random.randint(1,50,30),np.random.randint(1,50,30)]

# Sets up the map plot with coastlines from cartopy and the PlateCarree projection
# The PlateCarree projection is neither equal area nor conformal, thus it is 
mostly used for thematic mapping
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(9,5))
cmap=matplotlib.cm.RdBu_r 
norm=matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=50)
ax=plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(),extent=[-180, 180, -90, 90])
# Set labels and ticks for x- and y-axis
ax.set_xticks([-180, -120, -60, 0, 60, 120, 180], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_yticks([-90, -60, -30, 0, 30, 60, 90], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
plt.xlabel('Longitude [deg]')
plt.ylabel('Latitude [deg]')

plot = plt.scatter([], [], c=[], s=40, norm=norm, cmap=cmap, edgecolor="k")

def init():
    plot.set_offsets([])
    plot.set_array([])
    return plot,

def animate(i):
    data = np.hstack((nphi[i], nthe[i]))
    plot.set_offsets(data)
    plot.set_array(mag[i])
    return plot,

# Sets up colourbar and set a label
cbar=plt.colorbar()
cbar.set_label('Magnitude of SV [nT/yr$^2$]')

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, interval=800, blit=True)
```

Comment: It's not clear from the question or code which of [the possible options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46878531/4124317) you chose to show the animation.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I am using %matplotlib notebook.

Comment: Since blitting will not have any effect in the notebook anyways you can turn it off. Not sure if that changes anything though. Appart the code looks correct. If you can share a [mcve] I can investigate further.

Comment: Of course! Thanks for the help. I updated the post with a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: You mixed up `hstack` and `vstack`.