# repeat_delay parameter has no effect in animated plot in Jupyter

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, matplotlib-animation

I am making a simple animated scatter plot in a Jupyter notebook, and I want it to repeat, but with a delay before it loops. This is supposed to be set with the `repeat_delay` parameter, but it has no effect when I use it in a Jupyter notebook using `HTML(ani.to_html5_video())` to show the animation.

Here is a simple example of repositioning 20 points every 200 ms, but trying to add a 2 second delay before repeating the animation:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from IPython.display import HTML

frame_interval = 200
vid_repeat = True
repeat_delay = 2000  # set long so it would be obvious

def update_xy(i, scat):
    scat.set_offsets(np.random.random((20,2)))
    return scat,

fig = plt.figure()
init_data = np.random.random((20,3))
scat = plt.scatter(init_data[:,0], init_data[:,1], c=init_data[:,2], s=50, cmap = "hot")

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, 
                              update_xy, 
                              frames=numframes,
                              interval = frame_interval,
                              repeat = vid_repeat,
                              repeat_delay = repeat_delay,
                              fargs=(scat,))
plt.close(ani._fig)
HTML(ani.to_html5_video())
```

At the end, it just loops around at `frame_interval` no matter what value I put for `repeat_delay`. I get the same result when I save the animation `ani.save('foo.mp4')`, or try to play it using  `HTML(ani.to_jshtml())`.

**Related Questions**
[Animation in iPython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35532498/animation-in-ipython-notebook)
[How to animate a scatter plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401658/how-to-animate-a-scatter-plot)